# Can't install Python3 package in Debian 7

Tags: debian, package-management, python, aptitude

I get error while installing *python3* in Debian 7 (I have all updates installed):

```
root@nuclight:~# aptitude install python3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3 python3.2{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,621 kB of archives. After unpacking 8,991 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] 
Selecting previously unselected package python3.2.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.2-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 101541 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python3.2 (from .../python3.2_3.2.3-7_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.
Unpacking python3 (from .../python3_3.2.3-6_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up python3.2 (3.2.3-7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.2.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.2.postinst: python3.2: not found
dpkg: error processing python3.2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.2 (>= 3.2.3); however:
  Package python3.2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.2
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up python3.2 (3.2.3-7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.2.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.2.postinst: python3.2: not found
dpkg: error processing python3.2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.2 (>= 3.2.3); however:
  Package python3.2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.2
 python3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be the following line:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.2-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

Can you please run the following:

```
apt-get update
apt-get remove python3.*
apt-get install python3
```

This will remove all Python 3 Packages and then install Python 3 again. It seems your current install is slightly broken, as the `python3.2` binary which should be in the (already installed) `python3.2-minimal` package cannot be found.

Comment: `apt-get purge python3.*` might be better.